# Java Math issue incorrect output

Tags: java, math, modulo

(51^43)Mod77 in scientific calculator gives 2 as the output however,

(int)(Math.pow(51,43)%(double)77) gives 12 which should be 2 instead.

Can you please help ?

Answer (score 2):

```
    final BigInteger base = BigInteger.valueOf(51);
    final BigInteger exponent = BigInteger.valueOf(43);
    final BigInteger modulus = BigInteger.valueOf(77);
    System.out.println(base.modPow(exponent, modulus));
```

prints `2`.

Answer (score 1):

A `double` doesn't have enough precision to hold all the digits of `Math.pow(51,43)`. So when you take it `mod 77`, the answer is prone to significant rounding errors.

I suggest using `BigInteger` for arbitrary precision integer arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
(int)(Math.pow(51,43)%(double)77)
```

do:

```
(int)(Math.pow(51,43))%((double)77)
```

Comment: Why is there the cast to double? It is completely pointless as % is only defined for integer types and the left and right side of % get promoted to ints before % is applied.